# How do I deploy an APK file to a Galaxy Ace 4 Android phone?

Tags: android, deployment, apk, galaxy

I have created a game for Android and now want to deploy it to a physical phone to test it. Compiling it has created both an APK file and a signed APK file. I've been told that I want to use the signed one, but how do I get it onto my phone? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Ace 4 and I have a USB cable to connect it to my computer. How do I transfer the signed APK from my computer onto the phone and deploy it?

Comment: via `adb install /path/to/app_signed.apk`, but you probably using Android Studio, so clicking the "play" button will also do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, you can install the signed apk directly from the command line using adb install YOUR\Path\to\the\signed\yourgame.apk (make sure you have included the adb into your path in environment variable.

or just copy the apk into the internal memory of your phone, and in settings of your phone,search for something like allow the installation from untrusted scource.

Let me know if it didn't help.

Comment: So if the path to file was something like `D:/MyGame-Signed.apk`, I would open up the command line and just type `adb install D:/MyGame-Signed.apk` while the phone is connected to my computer?

Comment: yes, if you have adb included in the path of environment variable, just like you have java included in path of environment variable.